# Convert char * buffer to struct in cpp

Tags: c++, udp, buffer

I'm new to c and cpp, I want to know if there is a way to convert a char * buffer to struct taking into account that it could hold multiple 0x00 in the byte array. Ex. I have a struct header which I include in my cpp file.

```
struct ExampleStruct{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t message;
    int8_t param1;
    int16_t param2;
    int8_t param3;
    int8_t param4;
}
```

On my cpp file I have a udp server which receives N bytes, in a char * buffer; the buffer could look something like this:

```
char buffer[] = {0x0f, 0xff, 0x00, 0xd4, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff};
```

I tried doing this:

```
struct ExampleStruct exampleStruct;
memcpy(&exampleStruct, buffer, bytesReceived);
```

and this

```
struct ExampleStruct *exampleStruct = (ExampleStrcut *)buffer;
```

, but none work when I try to output for example exampleStruct.param4 in Hexadecimal it shows something else. Also, I do not have control over buffer message being sent.

How can I convert this to a struct, I tried to just cast it, but for some reason it casts incorrectly and I feel it could be due to having 0x00 in the byte array. Please help me cast it up to N bytes received.

Edit: Turns out the packets I was receiving were not structures and were RAW data which I had to deserialize manually one by one like the answer below.

Comment: Ignoring the obvious typo, `struct ExampleStruct *exampleStruct = (ExampleStrcut) *buffer;` should be `struct ExampleStruct *exampleStruct = (ExampleStrcut *) buffer;`, the second example is illegal. [The Strict Aliasing Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing) allows you to view any object as an array of characters, but the reverse is not permitted.

Comment: The `memcpy` approach is legal, but is vulnerable to getting the [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [alignment padding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment) wrong. I suspect padding is what you've tripped over here.

Comment: Padding/alignment could be different on the machine sending the data as well. A [mcve] would be helpful showing both how the data is sent and received. It would probably be best to serialize/deserialize the data rather than hoping it just lines up the same everywhere.

Comment: Simple example of padding in action: https://godbolt.org/z/79bfnacs7

Comment: @user4581301 thank you so much for this since I did follow memcpy, but did make sure I was fixing endianness since I was getting data from network. You are correct on the endianness part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, a safer method is to copy field by field or member by member.  This technique allows you to insert conversions for members (such as Little Endian to Big Endian).

```
struct ExampleStruct
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t message;
    int8_t param1;
    int16_t param2;
    int8_t param3;
    int8_t param4;

    void copy_from_buffer(uint8_t const * p_buffer)
    {
       id = *p_buffer;    p_buffer += sizeof(id);

       message = *((uint16_t *)(p_buffer));
       p_buffer += sizeof(message);

       param1 = *p_buffer; ++p_buffer;

       param2 = *((uint16_t *)(p_buffer));
       p_buffer += sizeof(param2);

       param3 = *p_buffer; ++p_buffer;
       param4 = *p_buffer; ++p_buffer;
    }
};
```

This removes the issue of padding in the struct, so no need for non-standard `pack` pragmas.

(Note:  Since OP tagged C++, I used a member function.)

Since the C++ language tag was selected, this could be adapted easily to a simple serialization interface:

```
class Serialize
{
    public:
        virtual void copy_from_buffer(uint8_t const * & p_buffer) const = 0;
        virtual size_t  size_in_buffer() const = 0;
        virtual void copy_to_buffer(uint8_t * & p_buffer) const = 0;
};
```

By passing the buffer pointer by reference, you can "chain" the calls by passing the same pointer.  This allows for easy integration of non-POD members in your `struct` or `class`.

The `size_in_buffer` method is used for allocating a destination buffer, since the size of the buffer may not be the same as the size of the structure (due to padding, alignment, etc.).

Comment: `*((uint16_t *)(p_buffer))` I think is undefined behavior technically, since some machines do not support unaligned loads.

Comment: Hmm...[SO] must have messed up the display or something--I didn't see this when I wrote my answer--if I had, I probably wouldn't have bothered writing one.

Comment: @JerryCoffin your answer is more complete than mine.  I have never considered using a template for Big/Little Endian conversion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you so much, I tried to do this, but for some reason the bytes were off. What made this better was following your advice, but I used `memcpy($variableName, buffer, sizeof(uint8_t));` then updating the buffer `buffer += sizeof(uint8_t);` depending of the type of data I was deserializing. Thanks I will give you an upvote for this! Again thank you so much!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews after that made sure to fix endianness

Answer (score 2):

To make this work in portable code, you generally have to handle conversions explicitly, one at a time, and you generally want to read the raw data into an array of `unsigned char`, so you can play bit-wise games with it easily/safely.

When I'm doing things like this, I usually define a `byte` class to make it easy to write out a byte as an unsigned number (`uint8_t` is usually an alias for `unsigned char`, so they print out as characters).

I also define a little template function to read big endian integers from a byte stream.

That's probably kind of overkill for this one struct, but if you're doing network communication, you'll probably end up with more uses for them.

Putting those all together the code would look something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class byte {
    unsigned char val;
public:
    byte(unsigned char val) : val(val) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, byte b) {
        return os << static_cast<uint16_t>(b.val & 0xff);
    }
};

template <class T>
T BigEndian(unsigned char const* buffer)
{
    T ret = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++) {
        T temp = static_cast<T>(buffer[i]);
        ret <<= CHAR_BIT;
        ret += temp;
    }
    return ret;
}

struct ExampleStruct {
    byte id;
    uint16_t message;
    byte param1;
    int16_t param2;
    byte param3;
    byte param4;

    ExampleStruct(unsigned char (&array)[8])
        : id(array[0])
        , message(BigEndian<uint16_t>(array+1))
        , param1(array[3])
        , param2(BigEndian<uint16_t>(array+4))
        , param3(array[6])
        , param4(array[7])
    { }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, ExampleStruct const &e) {
        return os << std::hex << "id: " << e.id
                  << ", message: " << e.message
                  << ", param1: " << e.param1
                  << ", param2: " << e.param2
                  << ", param3: " << e.param3
                  << ", param4: " << e.param4;
    }
};

int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[] = { 0x0f, 0xff, 0x00, 0xd4, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff };

    ExampleStruct s(buffer);

    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
id: f, message: ff00, param1: d4, param2: ff00, param3: 0, param4: ff
```

(which seems to be what I'd expect).

Of course, if your `uint16_t` items are little-endian (unusual for network data, but certainly possible nonetheless) you'd use a `LittleEdian<uint16_t>` instead (which would obviously treat the bytes in little-endian order).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things which can prevent memcpy solution working.

1. Alignment and padding. Every `uint16_t` address must be divisible by 2 (in most common cases) so C++ adds padding for your struct to make every `uint16_t` field aligned to 2 bytes:

```cpp
struct ExampleStruct{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t __padding0;
    uint16_t message;
    int8_t param1;
    uint8_t __padding1;
    int16_t param2;
    int8_t param3;
    uint8_t __padding2;
};
```

To avoid this, you can pack your struct:

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct ExampleStruct{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t message;
    int8_t param1;
    int16_t param2;
    int8_t param3;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

// Use it like this:
struct ExampleStruct exampleStruct;
memcpy(&exampleStruct, buffer, sizeof(ExampleStruct));
```

Note that I use `sizeof(ExampleStruct)` because you may receive more bytes than in your struct, and in such case you would end with copying untrusted data to your stack which can lead to serious vulnerabilities like Remote Code Execution.

You second example isn't allowed in C++ because type punning is undefined by C++ standard.

2. Consider which endianness used when encoding data. It is very probable that it is big endian in encoded message but your computer have little endian integers so every integer value would have bytes reverser.

Comment: Note that the packed struct  can lead you into significant performance issues (or outright failure) on some systems. [Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) may be a better option.

Comment: @user4581301 I am writing code to a compiler of Rust which just generates unaligned reads/writes for x86_64 target at this very moment because they are relatively fast on modern ones :) In most cases with packed structs, a compiler generates bits shifts and masking so it should work even in ARM despite it disallowing to access unaligned memory.

Comment: “Every uint16_t address must be divisible by 2” — there is no such requirement in C++. Some hardware might require it, but that is by no means universal.